How to recover my lost seed phrase
unfortunately, I lost access to my wallet. I only remember the first 10 of the 12 word seed phrase. how do I recover the last two. lets assume my seed phrase is dinner work badge avocado object blanket together jar early mass ? ? I used BTC recover but its not working

This question is similar to: Wallet recovery phrase. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
